# Combining two cte blocks

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to combine these two cte blocks without losing any records? My intent is to minimize the code duplication that is happening here. I need all records to appear in the results regardless of if they were in `cte1` or `cte2` or both.

**CTE 1 -**

```
with grouping (num, count) as 
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
where 
code = '1'
group by num
),
total (num, tot_count) as
(
select num, count(*)
from pay
group by num
)
select m.id, round(count/tot_count::decimal, 4), year
FROM total t
join grouping o
on t.num = o.num
join master m
on o.num = m.num;
```

**CTE 2 -**

```
with grouping (num, count) as 
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
where 
code = '2'
group by num
),
total (num, tot_count) as
(
select num, count(*)
from pay
group by num
)
select m.id, round(count/tot_count::decimal, 4), year
FROM total t
join grouping o
on t.num = o.num
join master m
on o.num = m.num;
```

Comment: Have you tried `Union` or `Union All`?

Comment: @gbeaven I have, but that doesn't solve my code duplication problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any sample data to test, but it appears the big difference is in your `WHERE` statement in the `grouping` CTE.

An [`IN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/) clause should do it for you:

```
with grouping (num, count) as 
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
where 
code IN ('1', '2')
group by num
),
total (num, tot_count) as
(
select num, count(*)
from pay
group by num
)
select m.id, round(count/tot_count::decimal, 4), year
FROM total t
join grouping o
on t.num = o.num
join master m
on o.num = m.num;
```

Confirmed that is the only difference in the queries using Sublime Text

[image]